# Why doesn't JQuery display UTF-8 chars properly?

Tags: php, jquery, utf-8

I know that JQuery is set to use the UTF-8 charset but this simply doesn't work out of the box on my website.

Even after setting UTF-8 manually in the header and forcing it in .htaccess JQuery still spits out the black diamond question mark for any special chars on the site.

I have seen other sites that have managed to do it properly but I can't get any special chars to display unless I encode to iso-8859-1.

The content is all being pulled with PHP/MySQL so maybe there is something I need to change on the tables as well? I thought that the header declaration would overwrite this anyway?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're forgetting to set a charset somewhere. What's your website?

Comment: Setting the encoding declaration in headers and actually sending UTF-8 encoded text are two different things; sounds like you're only doing one of the two.

Comment: @Deceze, Read that post that you suggested and went into MySQL and changed the collation to UTF-8 for the block that's giving me trouble but still no joy.

Comment: I can get it working properly if I declare iso-8859-1 so do I really need to change it to UTF-8? I mean is it going to cause any problems?

Comment: Then that means you are still outputting ISO-8859 encoded text!